# How to read the serial port with a arduino over python?

Tags: python, serial-port, arduino-uno

```
import serial 
ser= serial.Serial('com5',9600)
while 1:
Value_from_arduino = ser.readline()
Zustand = float(Value_from_arduino)
print(Zustand)
if Zustand == 1:
    ser.write(0)
    print('off')
    
elif Zustand == 0:
    ser.write(1)
    print(on)
```

This was the Python code, now here the arduino code.

```
char serialData;
int pin=12;
int pin2 = 5; 
int Value;
void setup(){
  pinMode(pin,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pin2,INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop(){
  Value = digitalRead(pin2);
  Serial.println(Value);
  delay(250);


while(Serial.available()){
serialData = Serial.read();
Serial.print(serialData);
 
if(serialData = '1'){
  digitalWrite(pin,HIGH);
  
  
  
  }
else if(serialData = '0'){
  digitalWrite(pin,LOW);
 
  
  
  }

  }
}
```

My problem is, when i run my python code, it stops when he gets the Value 0 from my arduino.
Here is the report from python:

```
    Zustand = float(Value_from_Arduino)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'\x000\r\n'
```

Python immediatly stops, but he puts the LED on.
The LED should be on if Python gets the value of 0, he do but then he just end run.
The LED should go on if value is 0 and of if value is 1.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decode the serial bytes from the serial port.

Replace the Zustand = line in your code

```
Value_from_arduino = ser.readline()
Zustand = float(ser_bytes[0:len(Value_from_arduino )-2].decode("utf-8"))
```

Please check here https://makersportal.com/blog/2018/2/25/python-datalogger-reading-the-serial-output-from-arduino-to-analyze-data-using-pyserial

also try, if encodings doesn't work well

```
import struct
Zustand, = struct.unpack('<f',Value_from_arduino )
```

Comment: thank you for your quick respond. Your line is not working, anyway you are right. i can decode the value but then he just give me the values and ignore my algorithm.

Comment: yes sorry, so my problem is, if i decode my value then my code is not working. if i use the float then my code is working, sends a signal to my arduino and then the code just break.

Comment: what error you are seeing? can you update your print statement

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Radiochemie/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    Zustand = float(Value_from_arduino.decode("utf-8"))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '\x001\r\n'

Comment: this error came with float. If i use the decode then my if functions are not working

Comment: try the struct method in the Answer i have added now

Comment: you can also try the decode method as 'Ascii' instead of 'utf-8'

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Radiochemie/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    Zustand = struct.unpack('<f',Value_from_arduino)
struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have found out please replace these lines of code

Steps -> Read,Decode to string, Strip /n and /r, Convert to float
please check here https://problemsolvingwithpython.com/11-Python-and-External-Hardware/11.04-Reading-a-Sensor-with-Python/

```
Value_from_arduino = ser.readline()
Value_from_arduino = Value_from_arduino.decode()
Value_from_arduino = Value_from_arduino.rstrip()
Zustand = float(Value_from_arduino)
```

Hope this Works..

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Radiochemie/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    Zustand = float(Value_from_arduino)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '\x000'

Comment: do you have instagramm?

Comment: Can you just do one last thing, replace your arduino code serial.write instead of serial.print in the arduino code?